# Pasar un parámetro a una Función

Tags: c#

A ver si se contaros. Tengo una función que es la siguiente

```
public int Modificar(..., Int16 idProvincia, ...)
.
.
w.Parameters.Add("@i_idProvincia", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 4).Value = idProvincia;
w.Parameters["@i_idProvincia"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
.
.
```

Y llamo a esa función de la siguiente manera:

```
Cprovincia.DataSource = dtProvincia;
Cprovincia.DisplayMember = "Nombre".Trim();
Cprovincia.ValueMember = "idProvincia";
.
.
.
Int16 idProvincia = (Int16)Cprovincia.SelectedValue;
.
.
.
bool pasa = objCliente.Modificar(...,idProvincia, ...);
```

El caso es que me da error al pasar la variable idProvincia y no se por qué. El error que me da es "No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo int en bool"

¿Qué hago mal? Porque le estoy pasando un valor Int16 que es smallint en la base de datos y, además, se lo estoy pasando bien en llamada a la función.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se debe a que tienes la función devuelve **un int y la igualas a un booleano** son dos tipos diferentes que requieren una conversión específica,
para arreglarlo puedes hacer sin tocar la función:

```
  bool pasa = objCliente.Modificar(...,idProvincia, ...)==0 ? false:true; //el qual 0 es la condicion de int que indique que fue mal.
```

Esto es equivalente al siguiente codigo para versiones de .net mas bajas:

```
bool pasa;

if(objCliente.Modificar(...,idProvincia, ...)==0)
   pasa=false;
else
   pasa=true;
```

Esta conversión recomiendo hacerla en el return más que aquí, ya que después sirve para donde pongas la función, pero si es el caso se tiene que cambiar que devuelve un booleano la función.

Comment: Pero ahora el fallo me da al ejecutar la función:
System.InvalidCastException: 'La conversión especificada no es válida.' y, supongo que viene derivada de la fila:
w.Parameters.Add("@i_idProvincia", SqlDbType.SmallInt, 4).Value = idProvincia;
w.Parameters["@i_idProvincia"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
Y esto es lo que está escrito en  la función que ha de devolver:
w.Parameters.Add("@o_Salida", SqlDbType.Bit, 1);
w.Parameters["@o_Salida"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
w.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (bool)w.Parameters["@o_Salida"].Value;

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo he arreglado, lo que he hecho ha sido convertir el parámetro de vuelta en int  y listos, lo he hecho así. Por un lado:

```
int pasa = objCliente.Modificar(...,idProvincia)==0 ? 0: 1;
```

por otro

```
w.Parameters.Add("@o_Salida", SqlDbType.Int, 1);
w.Parameters["@o_Salida"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

w.ExecuteNonQuery();
return (int)w.Parameters["@o_Salida"].Value;
```

Y arreglado. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.